# Javascript addHours function adding extra minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone-offset

I'm trying to add hours to a date but it shows an extra 12 minutes

the value of the date before executing the function is

```
Fri Jun 03 2016 15:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

After adding the hours, it becomes

```
Fri Jun 03 2016 06:12:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

MY code is

```
var ends = Date.parse(data['ends']); //data['ends'] = "2016-06-03 03:00:00-0700"
ends.addHours(tzOffset+DSTOffset); // tzOffset+DSTOffset = -9.30
```

expected result is `Fri Jun 03 2016 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-9.30 = 9 hours and 18 minutes  , and 30 minutes - 18 minutes gives you the 12 minutes you are having

it should be -9.5